# Are .tar.gz files made in Linux with identical files identical to .tar.gz files made in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, tar, gzip

I've produced a `.tar.gz` file in Windows that contains some files to update firmware via a Linux Device.  The update failed to take, and a Coworker mentioned the problem was because the `.tar.gz` did not have the `Linux signing` it's expecting to have. . .  Is this really a thing?  I have to assume it is, but I'm rather curious.  I know that text/xml files need to have `Unix LF` `EOL` conventions vs `Windows CRLF`, and I suspect my initial attempt failed because I forgot this initially.

***The main question here is whether or not a `.tar.gz` file made in `Windows` is identical to one made in `Linux`, and if so, how does one go about detecting/modifying this information in the `Windows Environment` programmatically?.  Is there a programmatical way in Windows to detect/force a .tar.gz file to be "`Linux Signed`" when there appears to be no relevant data from my own research, or is this a misconception from my Coworker? (Googling anything `.tar.gz` related for `Windows` produces many useless articles for this specific question. . .***

---

The information below is the best I can find from within the Windows OS across the different files in use. . .

I made the initial Package in 7-Zip, and the files inside were shown as -rwxrwxrwx inside the embedded .tar, with the .tar itself showing `FAT` for the `Host OS`
[image: FAT Host OS .tar File from first package - 7-Zip created]
[image: Files showing -rwxrwxrwx - 7-Zip created]

Next, I remade the package using the new `Windows Tar` commands (NEAT!!)
7-Zip shows the files inside as `-rw-rw-rw-` so I assume they're read-writable.  All other conventions necessary to make this process work match.  The only Difference aside from permissions was the `Host OS` showing `Unix` instead.
[image: Unix Host OS .tar File from second package - Windows Tar created]
[image: Files showing -rw-rw-rw- - Windows Tar created]

My Coworker then gave me a utility produced by our software team that produces nearly the same package I produced.  A few differences - the files inside are `-rw-r--r--` and the `Host OS` is listed as `FAT` just like 7-Zip.
[image: FAT Host OS .tar File from third package - Coworker's Utility created]
[image: Files showing -rw-r--r-- - Coworker's Utility Created]

Even though  my 2nd attempt "Worked" there were still some weird issues happening, and again he insisted it was because the .tar.gz files were not `Linux Signed` . . .  I'm calling a little misleading here, but would like to confirm if this is truly a thing, and if so, how does one programmatically detect / force a `.tar.gz` file to be `Linux Signed?`  Can this be done via `CMD` or `PowerShell`?  I'm fairly familiar with `VB.Net` / `c#` and `Batch` but not much else yet.

The first files were 'Read Only' according to the Coworker - assuming this is because it was `CRLF EOL` in the Linux System, and am believing the main issue is this.  I also assume the "weird" things happened due to me attempting to push the same package again.  (I believe our system does not have a mechanism built in to check if it was the same version as before vs after and so it never finishes. . .)

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux signed"?

Comment: Unless he's going to explain what he means by "linux signed" I'm calling male cow excrement. About the only difference is going to be that Linux tar is going to better retain the group, permissions and other filesystem information that is specific to Linux. It sounds like your coworker has no idea what the real issue is and is just parroting a line akin to "it works if you use Linux" while trying to sound like he actually has a clue.

Comment: Are you able to show a proper "Linux signed" file?

Comment: I showed screenshots from 3 separate files - the third of which is "Linux Signed" according to my coworker.  I too call male cow excrement, to the tenth degree, and wanted to confirm my suspicions more than anything.  To the point of Permissions and Group, (perhaps whether it's Root user permissions) - is there a way to force these settings inside Windows?  This is the only thing I could think of beyond some bizarre concept around certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to know if your co-worker has the wrong name for something or is just plain wrong.

"signing" would almost certainly refer to digitally signing something, and for that there would need to be a ***secret*** key that is not distributed to everyone.

There is no digital signature from Linux proving that it came from Linux.  If such a thing existed, it would need to be placed on every Linux machine and so would not be secret, thus would be utterly useless and prove nothing.  There's no reliable way to determine that a tar file came from a Linux machine.

Since you are discussing firmware updates, it is possible that the hardware is expecting content to be digitally signed by some third party. That is, the hardware could conceivably be refusing to accept any firmware that was not signed by the hardware vendor.  In that case the hardware vendor would hold the secret key and there would be nothing you could do to modify it.  That's the closest guess I have to make sense of your co-worker's comments.  Frankly it doesn't sound like that's what your co-worker meant.

Comment: This is about what I had expected, and wanted to confirm my theories - I found NOTHING around this anywhere else, and the only thing I could think of was around Certificates which does not apply to this specific instance.

Comment: As Mokubai mentioned in the other comments, the only things that may be unique to Linux would be the group, permissions, etc.  SO - this said - is this something which can be detected/changed/forced via Windows?  Or is it possible to force the allowance of Root access via Windows?

Comment: @k1dfr0std that would depend on the tool. If you have developers available you could try using the python library https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html most programmatic libraries should let you chose filemode and owner.

Comment: Do you know if there is a VB.Net based DLL / Library which accomplishes the same thing as this Python library?  I know nothing about Python but have built a few different things using VB.Net successfully.  (C# works too since they are translatable . . .)  Perhaps I will have to dive into Python but was hoping this would not require a new language to learn.  This link you shared points right back to Stack Overflow - very good reads.